# High memory usage and slow upload using AWS S3 TransferUtility

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I have created an application using C# and the AWS .Net SDK (v3.3.106.25) to upload some database backup files to a S3 bucket.  The application is currently unusable as memory usage goes up to 100% and uploads of files take progressively longer.

I am trying to upload 3 files, 2 of which are about 1.45GB and one is about 4MB.  I am using the TransferUtility method as I understand that it utilises multi part uploads.  I have set the part size to 16MB.  Each file is uploaded consecutively.  Here are some facts about the upload:

File 1 - 4MB - upload duration 4 seconds

File 2 - 1.47GB - upload duration 11.5 minutes

File 3 - 1.45GB - upload duration 1 hour 12 minutes before killing the process as PC became unusable

I am running this on a Windows 10 machine with 16GB RAM and Intel Core i7 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Here is my upload code:

```
private async Task UploadFileAsync(string keyName, string filePath, int partSizeMB, S3StorageClass  storageClass)
{
    try
    {
        using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_region))
        {
            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

            var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = _bucketName,
                FilePath = filePath,
                StorageClass = storageClass,
                PartSize = partSizeMB * 1024 * 1024,    // set to 16MB
                Key = keyName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private
            };

            await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
        }

    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
    {
        string errMsg = string.Format("Error encountered on server. Message:{0} when writing an object", e.Message);
        System.Exception argEx = new System.Exception(errMsg, e.InnerException);
        throw argEx;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string errMsg = string.Format("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
        System.Exception argEx = new System.Exception(errMsg, e.InnerException);
        throw argEx;
    }

}
```

This code is being called 3 times in a loop with each call awaited.

Can anyone please suggest how I can upload these files in a more efficient manner.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have decided to abandon the use of the high level TransferUtility API method as it doesn't seem fit for purpose for large files.  It seems that it loads the whole file into memory before splitting it into parts and uploading each part.  For large files it just consumes all available memory and your server can grind to a halt.

For anyone interested this is how I have solved the issue:

1. I now use the low level api methods InitiateMultipartUploadAsync,UploadPartAsync and CompleteMultipartUploadAsync and manage the multi part upload myself.
2. The key to making this work is the use of the .Net MemoryMappedFile class and the CreateViewStream method to manage only retrieving the parts of the file into memory one at a time.
3. I use a Queue to control which parts have been uploaded and also to retry any individual parts that might have failed.

Here is my new code:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Linq;
using Amazon.Runtime;


public class S3Upload
{
    // declarations
    private readonly string _bucketName;
    private readonly RegionEndpoint _region;

    //event handlers
    public event EventHandler<ProgressUpdatedEventArgs> OnProgressUpdated;

    private bool CheckFilePath(string filePath)
    {
        // check the filePath exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public async Task UploadFileMultiPartAsync(string keyName, string filePath, string storageClass,
                                        int partSizeMB = 16, int retryWaitInterval = 60000,
                                        int maxRetriesOnFail = 10)
    {
        if (CheckFilePath(filePath))
        {
            long fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
            long partSize = partSizeMB * (long)Math.Pow(1024, 2);
            partSize = GetPartSize(fileSize, partSize);
            S3StorageClass sClass = new S3StorageClass(storageClass);

            try
            {
                await UploadFileMultiPartAsync(keyName, filePath, fileSize, partSize, sClass, retryWaitInterval, maxRetriesOnFail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string errMsg = string.Format("Cannot find file {0}.  Check the file exists and that the application has access permissions.", filePath);
            System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException argEx = new System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException(errMsg);
            throw argEx;
        }
    }

    private async Task UploadFileMultiPartAsync(string keyName, string filePath, long fileSize,
                                                    long partSize, S3StorageClass storageClass,
                                                    int retryWaitInterval,
                                                    int maxRetriesOnFail)
    {
        int retryCount = 0;
        long offset = 0;
        // we need to calculate the number of parts based on the fileSize and partSize
        int iterations = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileSize / (double)partSize);
        int currentIterations = iterations;
        // create a queue of indexes to be processed.  Indexes will be removed from this list as the
        // uploads are processed.  If the upload is not successful then it will be re-added to the end
        // of the queue for later retry.  We pause after each full loop is completed before starting the retry
        Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, iterations));
        // the following 2 variables store values returned from the S3 call and are persisted throughout the loop
        string uploadId = "";
        List<PartETag> eTags = new List<PartETag>();
        // Create the memory-mapped file. 
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, "uploadFile"))
        {
            while (q.Count > 0)
            {
                int iPart = q.Dequeue();
                offset = iPart * partSize;
                long chunkSize = (offset + partSize > fileSize) ? fileSize - offset : partSize;
                using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(offset, chunkSize))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = binReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                        //convert to stream
                        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(bytes, false);

                        bool lastPart = (q.Count == 0) ? true : false;

                        UploadResponse response = await UploadChunk(keyName, uploadId, iPart, lastPart, mStream, eTags, iterations);
                        uploadId = response.uploadId;
                        eTags = response.eTags;

                        if (!response.success)
                        {
                            // the upload failed so we add the failed index to the back of the 
                            // queue for retry later
                            q.Enqueue(iPart);
                            lastPart = false;
                        }
                        // if we have attempted an upload for every part and some have failed then we
                        // wait a bit then try resending the parts that failed.  We try this a few times
                        // then give up.
                        if (!lastPart && iPart == currentIterations - 1)
                        {
                            if (retryCount < maxRetriesOnFail)
                            {
                                currentIterations = q.Count;
                                Thread.Sleep(retryWaitInterval);
                                retryCount += 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // reached maximum retries so we abort upload and raise error
                                try
                                {
                                    await AbortMultiPartUploadAsync(keyName, uploadId);
                                    string errMsg = "Multi part upload aborted. Some parts could not be uploaded. Maximum number of retries reached.";
                                    throw new Exception(errMsg);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    string errMsg = string.Format("Multi part upload failed. Maximum number of retries reached.  Unable to abort upload. Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                                    throw new Exception(errMsg);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task AbortMultiPartUploadAsync(string keyName, string uploadId)
    {
        using (var _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_region))
        {
            AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = _bucketName,
                Key = keyName,
                UploadId = uploadId
            };
            await _s3Client.AbortMultipartUploadAsync(abortMPURequest);
        }
    }

    private async Task<UploadResponse> UploadChunk(string keyName, string uploadId, int chunkIndex, bool lastPart, MemoryStream stream, List<PartETag> eTags, int numParts)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_region))
            {
                var partNumber = chunkIndex + 1;

                // Step 1: build and send a multi upload request
                // we check uploadId == "" rather than chunkIndex == 0 as if the initiate call failed on the first run
                // then chunkIndex = 0 would have been added to the end of the queue for retries and uploadId
                // will still not have been initialized, even though we might be on a later chunkIndex
                if (uploadId == "")
                {
                    var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = _bucketName,
                        Key = keyName
                    };

                    InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse = await _s3Client.InitiateMultipartUploadAsync(initiateRequest);
                    uploadId = initResponse.UploadId;
                }

                // Step 2: upload each chunk (this is run for every chunk unlike the other steps which are run once)
                var uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    Key = keyName,
                    UploadId = uploadId,
                    PartNumber = partNumber,
                    InputStream = stream,
                    IsLastPart = lastPart,
                    PartSize = stream.Length
                };

                // Track upload progress.
                uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress +=
                    (_, e) => OnPartUploadProgressUpdate(numParts, uploadRequest, e);

                UploadPartResponse uploadResponse = await _s3Client.UploadPartAsync(uploadRequest);

                //Step 3: build and send the multipart complete request
                if (lastPart)
                {
                    eTags.Add(new PartETag
                    {
                        PartNumber = partNumber,
                        ETag = uploadResponse.ETag
                    });

                    var completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = _bucketName,
                        Key = keyName,
                        UploadId = uploadId,
                        PartETags = eTags
                    };

                    CompleteMultipartUploadResponse result = await _s3Client.CompleteMultipartUploadAsync(completeRequest);
                    return new UploadResponse(uploadId, eTags, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    eTags.Add(new PartETag
                    {
                        PartNumber = partNumber,
                        ETag = uploadResponse.ETag
                    });

                    return new UploadResponse(uploadId, eTags, true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return new UploadResponse(uploadId, eTags, false);
        }


    }

    private class UploadResponse
    {
        public string uploadId { get; set; }
        public List<PartETag> eTags { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }

        public UploadResponse(string Id, List<PartETag> Tags, bool succeeded)
        {
            uploadId = Id;
            eTags = Tags;
            success = succeeded;
        }
    }

    private void OnPartUploadProgressUpdate(int numParts, UploadPartRequest request, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
    {
        // Process event. 
        if (OnProgressUpdated != null)
        {
            int partIndex = request.PartNumber - 1;
            int totalIncrements = numParts * 100;
            int percentDone = (int)Math.Floor((double)(partIndex * 100 + e.PercentDone) / (double)totalIncrements * 100);
            OnProgressUpdated(this, new ProgressUpdatedEventArgs(percentDone));
        }
    }

    private long GetPartSize(long fileSize, long partSize)
    {
        // S3 multi part limits
        //====================================
        // min part size = 5MB
        // max part size = 5GB
        // total number of parts = 10,000
        //====================================

        if (fileSize < partSize)
        {
            partSize = fileSize;
        }

        if (partSize <= 0)
        {
            return Math.Min(fileSize, 16 * (long)Math.Pow(1024, 2));    // default part size to 16MB
        }

        if (partSize > 5000 * (long)Math.Pow(1024, 2))
        {
            return 5000 * (long)Math.Pow(1024, 2);
        }

        if (fileSize / partSize > 10000)
        {
            return (int)(fileSize / 10000);
        }

        return partSize;
    }

}

public class ProgressUpdatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ProgressUpdatedEventArgs(int iPercentDone)
    { PercentDone = iPercentDone; }
    public int PercentDone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm taking a look at this, as we are running into similar issues; but am curious if you have a few dependencies elsewhere! Specifically I am having trouble seeing any references to `ProgressUpdatedEventArgs`, `OnProgressUpdated`, and `CheckFilePath` within your block. Thank you a ton for writing all of this out, by the way - it is super appreciated!

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, there were a couple of dependencies not included in my original snippet.  I have updated the post to include all required dependencies, using statements and methods.